# ColdFusion ArrayContains issue

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

**Question:** I am trying to check to see if the value of my variable user_ID is in one of the arrays I have created?

**Background:** I am not sure if my syntax is correct I have posted it below with the error I am getting from my cfcatch.

```
<cfargument name="usr_ID" required="yes">

<cfset arrRFQUsers = [ "1346", "2246", "130","2223", "3712", "24","6444", "6953", "7240"] />

<cfset arrRFQAdmin = [ "599", "10", "28","45","7420", "7340"] />



<cfif  #ArrayContains(arrRFQUsers, usr_ID)# >

        <cfset userReturn = "rfqUser">


<elseif  #ArrayContains(arrRFQAdmin, usr_ID)# >

    <cfset userReturn = "rfqAdmin">

<elseif>


    <cfset userReturn = "Not Set">


</cfif>

        <cfreturn userReturn>
```

This is the error I am seeing:

```
Other Error: Expression

Message: Variable USERRETURN is undefined.
Detail:
```

Comment: Ugh. You don't need any of those `#` signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an `<elseif>` tag in ColdFusion (unless it was introduced recently), but in any case, the last part of the `<cfif>` should just be `<cfelse>` rather than `<cfelseif>`:

```
<cfif ArrayContains(arrRFQUsers, usr_ID)>
    <cfset userReturn = "rfqUser">
<cfelseif ArrayContains(arrRFQAdmin, usr_ID)>
    <cfset userReturn = "rfqAdmin">
<cfelse>
    <cfset userReturn = "Not Set">
</cfif>

<cfreturn userReturn>
```

Note that I've removed your extraneous hash marks `#` which aren't necessary here.

I also recommend setting a default value at the beginning, before the `<cfif>`, so you can be certain that the value will exist. I would also advise you to scope your variables explicitly (e.g., use `arguments.usr_ID` rather than `usr_ID`, and put your function variables into the `local` scope):

```
<cfargument name="usr_ID" required="yes">

<cfset local.arrRFQUsers = [ "1346", "2246", "130","2223", "3712", "24","6444", "6953", "7240"] />
<cfset local.arrRFQAdmin = [ "599", "10", "28","45","7420", "7340"] />

<cfset local.userReturn = "Not Set" />
<cfif ArrayContains(local.arrRFQUsers, arguments.usr_ID)>
    <cfset local.userReturn = "rfqUser" />
<cfelseif ArrayContains(local.arrRFQAdmin, arguments.usr_ID)>
    <cfset local.userReturn = "rfqAdmin" />
</cfif>

<cfreturn local.userReturn />
```

Comment: So far so good. I added your example and so far to error. I will continue to test and mark this as accepted. Thanks for your help +1

Comment: Another thing you might consider is using lists instead of arrays. That would be really helpful too if you're pulling values through a query as you can use `valueList()` to get a list of values.

Comment: I would think that arrays would be faster because lists are just delimited strings

Comment: @JamesAMohler, you may be right about that. So used to working with lists that I did not consider that.